# keras: how to use learning rate decay with model.train_on_batch()

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

In my current project I'm using keras' `train_on_batch()` function to train since the `fit()` function does not support the alternating training of generator and discriminator required for GAN's. 
Using (for example) the Adam optimizer I have to specify the learning rate decay in the constructor with `optimizer = Adam(decay=my_decay)` and hand this to the models compiling method. 
This work fine if I use the model's `fit()` function afterwards, since that takes care of counting the training repetitions internally, but I don't know how I can set this value myself using a construct like

```
counter = 0
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for batch_idx in range(0, number_training_samples, BATCH_SIZE):
        # get training batch:
        x = ...
        y = ...
        # calculate learning rate:
        current_learning_rate = calculate_learning_rate(counter)
        # train model:
        loss = model.train_on_batch(x, y)    # how to use the current learning rate?
```

with some function to calculate the learning rate. 
How can i set the current learning rate manually?

If there are mistakes in this post I'm sorry, it's my first question here.

Thank you already for any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### EDIT

In 2.3.0, `lr` was renamed to `learning_rate`: [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/36098bf0d7ca1e8285f63963130877746dc2809d#diff-1690a6925eefd029b3bebb7148e87612). In older versions you should use `lr` instead (thanks @Bananach).

Set value with a help of keras backend: `keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, learning_rate)` (where `learning_rate` is a float, desired learning rate) works for the `fit` method and should work for the train_on_batch:

```
from keras import backend as K


counter = 0
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for batch_idx in range(0, number_training_samples, BATCH_SIZE):
        # get training batch:
        x = ...
        y = ...
        # calculate learning rate:
        current_learning_rate = calculate_learning_rate(counter)
        # train model:
        K.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, current_learning_rate)  # set new learning_rate
        loss = model.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/36098bf0d7ca1e8285f63963130877746dc2809d#diff-1690a6925eefd029b3bebb7148e87612 it should be `model.optimizer.learning_rate`